# Question about proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and came up with the following:

$$ |u||v|\cos{\theta} \leq \frac{1}{2}|u|^2 + \frac{1}{2}|v|^2 $$

I got stuck here, did some googling and found a proof that was similar to mine on [AoPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Cauchy-Schwarz_Inequality) (or up to where I got, they just expanded less than I did):

> Consider:
>   $$ \langle a-b, a-b\rangle = \langle a,a\rangle + \langle b,b \rangle -2 \langle a,b \rangle $$
>   Since this is always $\geq 0$ we have:
>   $$ \langle a, b \rangle \leq \frac{1}{2}\langle a, a \rangle + \frac{1}{2} \langle b, b \rangle $$

Now this is where I start to get lost:

> ...[handles zero case]. Now, we may normalize so that $\langle a,a \rangle = \langle b,b \rangle = 1$. Therefore:
>   $$ \langle a, b \rangle \leq 1 = \langle a, a \rangle^{1/2}\langle b, b \rangle^{1/2} $$
>   QED.

Here though I don't understand. Why are we allowed to normalize these two values? Mainly, I am confused about when the length of the two vectors are in the range of $(0,1)$, since in this case:

$$ \langle a, a\rangle^{1/2} \langle b,b \rangle^{1/2} \leq 1$$

As well, which leads me to believe there is still a chance that:

$$\langle a,b \rangle > \langle a, a\rangle^{1/2} \langle b,b \rangle^{1/2} $$

Can you help me with my confusion? In essence, I have doubts about the normalization used, and need further reassurance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have proved the inequality
$$|\langle u, v\rangle| \leq 1$$
where $\|u\| = \|v\| = 1$. Now suppose that $a$ and $b$ are any nonzero vectors. Then $u = a/\|a\|$ and $v = b/\|b\|$ are unit vectors, so the inequality applies:
$$|\langle u, v\rangle| \leq 1$$
Plugging in $u = a/\|a\|$ and $v = b/\|b\|$:
$$\left|\left\langle \frac{a}{\|a\|}, \frac{b}{\|b\|} \right\rangle \right|\leq 1$$
By linearity of the inner product, we can pull out the $\|a\|$ and $\|b\|$:
$$\frac{1}{\|a\|\|b\|} \left|\left\langle a, b \right\rangle\right| \leq 1$$
Multiplying both sides by $\|a\|\|b\|$, we obtain the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$\left|\left\langle a, b \right\rangle\right| \leq \|a\|\|b\|$$

Comment: When I read this proof, it makes sense. But, the original proof doesn't use the properties of linearity to prove the inequality. On one hand, you have confirmed beyond doubt that the proof has confirmed beyond doubt that it must work in the interval $(0,1)$, but by doing something (that feels) different altogether. Is there way to justify the current outline of proof? Sorry if what I am saying doesn't make sense.

Comment: O wait, I think I understand...

Comment: I see, the usage of the unit vector is kind of like justification for normalization, ok, ok. Sorry, I didn't stare at it hard enough I guess.

Comment: @user667648: Yes, that's right. The proof works fine for any nonzero $\|a\|$ and $\|b\|$, whether they are greater or smaller than 1 makes no difference.

Comment: @user667648: To elaborate on my previous comment, if $\|a\| > 1$, then dividing $a$ by $\|a\|$ shrinks it down to a unit vector. If $\|a\| < 1$, then dividing by $a$ expands it to a unit vector.